# Regular expression that uses balancing groups

Tags: c#, .net, regex, balancing-groups

I have a basic text template engine that uses a syntax like this:

```
foo bar
%IF MY_VAR
  some text
  %IF OTHER_VAR
    some other text
  %ENDIF
%ENDIF
bar foo
```

I have an issue with the regular expression that I am using to parse it whereby it is not taking into account the nested IF/ENDIF blocks.

The current regex I'm using is: `%IF (?<Name>[\w_]+)(?<Contents>.*?)%ENDIF`

I have been reading up on balancing capture groups (a feature of .NET's regex library) as I understand this is the recommended way of supporting "recursive" regex's in .NET.

I've been playing with balancing groups and have so far came up with the following:

```
(
 (
  (?'Open'%IF\s(?<Name>[\w_]+))
  (?<Contents>.*?)
 )+
 (
  (?'Close-Open'%ENDIF)(?<Remainder>.*?)
 )+
)*
(?(Open)(?!))
```

But this is not behaving entirely how I would expect. It is for instance capturing a lot of empty groups. Help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To capture a whole IF/ENDIF block with balanced IF statements, you can use this regex:

```
%IF\s+(?<Name>\w+)
(?<Contents>
    (?> #Possessive group, so . will not match IF/ENDIF
        \s|
        (?<IF>%IF)|     #for IF, push
        (?<-IF>%ENDIF)| #for ENDIF, pop
        . # or, anything else, but don't allow
    )+
    (?(IF)(?!)) #fail on extra open IFs
)   #/Contents
%ENDIF
```

The point here is this: you *cannot* capture in a single `Match` more than one of every named group. You will only get one `(?<Name>\w+)` group, for example, of the last captured value. In my regex, I kept the `Name` and `Contents` groups of your simple regex, and limited the balancing inside the `Contents` group - the regex is still wrapped in `IF` and `ENDIF`.

If becomes interesting when your data is more complex. For example:

```
%IF MY_VAR             
  some text
  %IF OTHER_VAR
    some other text
  %ENDIF
  %IF OTHER_VAR2
    some other text 2
  %ENDIF
%ENDIF                 
%IF OTHER_VAR3         
    some other text 3
%ENDIF
```

Here, you will get two matches, one for `MY_VAR`, and one for `OTHER_VAR3`. If you want to capture the two ifs on `MY_VAR`'s content, you have to rerun the regex on its `Contents` group (you can get around it by using a lookahead if you must - wrap the whole regex in `(?=...)`, but you'll need to put it into a logical structure somehow, using positions and lengths).

Now, I won't explain too much, because it seems you get the basics, but a short note about the contents group - I've uses a possessive group to avoid backtracking. Otherwise, it would be possible for the dot to eventually match whole `IF`s and break the balance. A lazy match on the group would behave similarly (`( )+?` instead of `(?> )+`).

Comment: All that aside, consider using a parser, it should take care of it easily.

Comment: That's brilliant. Thank you very much. I've added some recursion into my program so that it traverses the nested if/endif blocks.

Comment: Minor issue that's hopefully easy to fix... consider this input text: `%IF MY_VAR some text %IF OTHER_VAR %ENDIF`. Notice that the inner OTHER_VAR is not closed with an ENDIF. However the regex matches the inner block rather than matching on the outer block. How can I make the regex, in this particular scenario (i.e. malformed template), match on the outer-most block rather than jumping straight to the inner block?

Comment: @NathanE - Good question! I was going to add a paragraph about invalid input, but though it was too long as it is... I'm not sure there's an easy way to solve that problem - the balancing groups are there to *avoid matching* in case of mismatched groups, it's hard to add rule for the "right" behavior in that case (for that matter, this regex captures a balanced if, which is "right"). You might fall back on your original regex. If you want to define clear rules, you might need to write a grammar and parser - it allows fine tuning, and can provide better parsing error messages.

Comment: No problem. It is still a great regex you came up with Kobi. If the need arises in the future to have a more graceful error handling condition for a malformed template, or maybe to add more types of tokens to the template language, then I will very likely just redesign it to be a proper parsing engine. I think the regex will do just fine until that day though!

Comment: Looking again at the question, it is probably possible to capture all IFs in a single Match, using Groups and Captures. Maybe I'll update the answer if needed, I didn't know that at the time...