# Using regex to find items encapsulated in [] and then replace them

Tags: c#, regex

So i have some strings which I want to replace some occurrences of brackets in.

Now this is what I've done so far. And it works

```
string answerText = "This is an [example] string";
Match match = Regex.Match(answerText, @"\[(.*?)\]");

if(match.Success)
{
    if(match.Value.Equals("[example]"))
    {
        answerText = answerText.Replace(match.Value, "awsome");
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how to make this happen if the answer text looks something like this

```
string answerText = "This is an [example1] [example2] [example3] string";
```

Comment: More generally you might want to look at balanced regexs e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284827/regular-expression-that-uses-balancing-groups

Comment: Surely you aren't just looking for the [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx) method? *Within a specified input string, replaces all strings that match a regular expression pattern with a specified replacement string.*

Comment: no nesting, I'm thinking if Regex.Matches could be an option to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by using the solution I suggested in my original post looping through the string several times until I got no match.

Answer (score 3):

Is there any reason why you're not doing this instead of using regexes?

```
string answerText = "This is an [example] string";
answerText.Replace("[example]", "awsome");
```

Comment: maybe he does not know what the text between the brackets will be??

Comment: @CodeMonkey, that was my thought too. The regex used supports that hypothesis.

Comment: Hence the question mark. The question seems to indicate he's going to test the match against actual values to see if he needs to replace them, in which case you don't need to use Regex...

Comment: The values within the brackets can be anything so .replace is a bit to simple

Answer (score 1):

What about this

```
string answerText = "This is an [example1] [example2] [example3] string";
string pattern = @"\[(.*?)\]";
answerText = Regex.Replace(answerText, pattern, "awesome");
```

Comment: Hint: The question mark makes the pattern "lazy", i.e. using the shortest match available. Combine this with the Replace-Overload with a callback function and you will be able to "switch case" over your pattern...

Comment: Wouldn't this replace all [whatever] with "awesome" ?

Comment: @Trikks yes thats what this is doing.

Comment: Alright, I need to be able to have dynamic replacements. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Trikks have a look at [MatchEvaluator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SYSTEM.TEXT.REGULAREXPRESSIONS.MATCHEVALUATOR);k(MATCHEVALUATOR);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true) this fits to the comment of eFloh and should meet your requirement of dynamical replacements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Replace method of Regex something like below.

```
     Regex.Replace(inputString, "\\[" + matchValue + "\\]", "ReplaceText", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Hope this helps!!